# How to make a partial view load when the view first loads?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I finally learned how to use `Ajax.BeginForm` to make a table refresh when submitting select choices in the BeginForm block.

When I click "submit" the partial view loads as intended, every time, so that functionality is dialed in.

What I have not been able to find is how I tell the Controller to load the Partial View when the View first loads, using the default values in the Index Action. (The Partial View supports the Index Action).

Is this something I can do from the Controller or does it need to be jQuery?

To provide more context, the following code is what currently works -- that is, the partial view loads only when the form is submitted, but doesn't show on first View load.

**View:**

```
@model ViewModelTest.ViewModels.StudentBehaviorDetailBySemesterViewModel

// ... code ...

@using (Ajax.BeginForm(actionName: "PartialTable",
    controllerName: "StudentBehaviorDetailBySemester",
    ajaxOptions: new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "TableData" }))
{
    <div>
        <p>Campus: @Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.SelectedCampus, Model.CampusList)</p>
        <p>FY: @Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.SelectedFy, Model.FyList)</p>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </div>
}

<div id="TableData">
    @{Html.Action("PartialTable", "StudentBehaviorDetailBySemester"
          , new { vm = Model });}
</div>


@section scripts
{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
}
```

**Controller -- Index and Partial View**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(string SelectedCampus="MRA", string SelectedFy="FY16")
{
    StudentBehaviorDetailBySemesterViewModel vm 
      = new StudentBehaviorDetailBySemesterViewModel();    
    vm.SelectedCampus = SelectedCampus;
    vm.SelectedFy = SelectedFy;

    vm.CampusList = new SelectList(Repositories.SelectLists.CampusList());
    vm.FyList = new SelectList(Repositories.SelectLists.FiscalYearList());
    return View(vm);
}


public ActionResult PartialTable(StudentBehaviorDetailBySemesterViewModel vm)
{
    using (TestAccountContext db = new TestAccountContext())
    {
        var query = db.StudentBehaviorDetailBySemesters
            .Where(m => m.Campus == vm.SelectedCampus)
            .Where(m => m.Fy == vm.SelectedFy).ToList();
        vm.BehaviorDetail = query;
    }

    return PartialView("PartialTable", vm);
}
```

Comment: Your `Html.Action()` line of code will render the partial view. What problems are you having?

Comment: I want the partial view to load when the page _first_ loads, using default values, which it doesn't do. I have to press "submit" for the partial view to show.

Comment: Use `@{Html.RenderAction("PartialTable", "StudentBehaviorDetailBySemester", new { vm = Model });}`

Comment: @SeM, is correct. Its either `@Html.Action(....)` or `@{ Html.RenderAction(...); }`

Comment: @SeM -- That worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
@{Html.Action("PartialTable", "StudentBehaviorDetailBySemester", new { vm = Model });}
```

You need to use:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("PartialTable", "StudentBehaviorDetailBySemester", new { vm = Model });}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to render a partial view you have update your partial view syntax...

```
@{Html.RenderAction("PartialTable", "ControllerName", new { vm = Model });}
```